# UI controls' width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have following UI hierarchy

Scroll View -->TableLayout-->Rows [each row has TextView+EditText]

**Problem**
Inside a row, each View should not exceed 50% of width of parent (TableRow). if an EditText is created to enter, say Username with max characters N; then width of EditText ideally should be exactly N chars long but must not exceed 50% limit.

I've tried many permutations and combination and could not get it right so far.

I have to do it programmatically as per the project requirement.

thanks.

Comment: show your code here. so that any one can help you

Comment: if you want to limit character you can use android:maxLength="10"

Comment: @AndroidTechMe my code is what 'ask' has suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to scrap TableLayout in order to be my own layouts effective. Layout params in TableRows seems ineffective. LinearLayout looks more flexible.

Now I have following Layout hierarchy and it works.

Scroll View -->LinearLayout instead of TableLayout--> [Individual fields encapuslated in LinearLayout instead of TableRows]

Answer (score 0):

Try using layout weight like this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </EditText>

</TableRow>
```

To do it programmatically, try using LayoutParams to accomplish the same like this:

```
 TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);

 TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
 TableLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 tr.setLayoutParams(trparams);

 textview1 = new TextView(this);
 edittext1 = new EditText(this);

 TableRow.LayoutParams fieldparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
 tr.addView(textview1, fieldparams);
 tr.addView(edittext1, fieldparams);

 table.addView(tr);
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but it fixes the width of Views to exactly 50% each. However it should be the upper limit, if, say only 5 chars to be entered in an EditText, then it should be 5 chars long. 50% space is too long in that case and doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0):

i saw your comment to ask's answers.i think you can set the width of edittext or textview as wrap content.and set the max width property of those controls as 50% of the screen.then it's width will not exceed the 50% of the parent width.

Comment: not working. did you try it? setXXXWidth methods seem to be ineffective.